# Adding lines and labels at custom positions in BarLegend

Tags: plotting, legending

Currently my BarLegend looks like:

```
BarLegend[{(ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[#, {0, .125}]] &) , {0, .11} }]
```

[image: Barlgend]

I would like to add white (maybe dotted) lines to Barlegend at positions {0.02, 0.04, ...} such that it looks like

[image: Barlegend with lines]

Since I'm not only creating one plot & BarLegend, I'd also like to manually place the ticks & labels of BarLegend to make sure the ticks & labels are at the same positions as the white lines. For example: I'd like to place the ticks, labels, and white lines at {0.03, 0.06, 0.09}.

How can I achieve the lines and the custom placement?

Answer (score 8):

```
incRange = 0.020;
maxRange = 0.120;

BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, maxRange}}, 
          Ticks -> Table[i, {i, incRange, maxRange - incRange, incRange}],  
          TickLengths -> 25, RotateTicks -> 180,   
          TicksStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1], White, Dashed, FontColor -> Black], 
          LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 12}, LegendMarkerSize -> {20, 300}]
```

[image]

Comment: I get the BarLegend without the text. Can this be version dependent? I use Mathematica 9 and Ticks, TickLengths, RotateTicks, and TicksStyle  are marked in red color.

Comment: The labels are hidden, because the barlegend isn't wide enough. Stretching the legend gives: 
https://s19.postimg.org/e50h22t5v/post3.jpg

Is there any other solution?

Comment: And the labels are on the left in your solution. I'd need them on the right.

Comment: Maybe a possible solution is to not use BarLegend at all, but use another Contoutplot as the Legend.

Answer (score 5):

Thank you for your post, but I now plot the Legend with a Contourplot and get the full control over all options:

```
plotoptions = {ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][
       Rescale[#, {0, .125}]] &), 
   MeshFunctions -> 
    Table[#3 &, {i, 1, Length[{0, .025, .05, .075, .1, .125}]}], 
   Mesh -> Table[{{tick, 
       Lighter[White, 
        HeavisideTheta[(tick/
            Max[{0, .025, .05, .075, .1, .125}]) - .5]]}}, {tick, {0, \
.025, .05, .075, .1, .125}[[2 ;; -2]]}], 
   MeshStyle -> {Dotted, DotDashed, Dashed, AbsoluteThickness[.5]}};

ContourPlot[y, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, .125}, Contours -> 100, 
 ContourLines -> False, PlotRange -> All, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> 
  False,(*Frame\[Rule]{{False,True},{False,False}},*)
 FrameStyle -> Directive[RGBColor[.8, .8, .8], FontColor -> Black], 
 FrameTicks -> {{None, {0, .025, .05, .075, .1, .125}}, {None, None}},
  AspectRatio -> 10, ImageSize -> 50, Evaluate@plotoptions]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

One can use the undocumented option `"StyledContours"` to add individually styled lines to a `BarLegend`.

```
BarLegend[{(ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[#, {0, .125}]] &), {0, .11}}, 
 "StyledContours" -> {{0.02, Directive[White, Dotted]}, {0.04, White}, {0.06, Red}, 
                      {0.08, White}, {0.1, Black}}]
```

[image: Out]

Ticks, labels, and white lines at a list of tick positions:

```
ticks = {0.03, 0.06, 0.09};
BarLegend[{(ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[#, {0, .125}]] &), {0, .11}}, 
 "StyledContours" -> Transpose[{ticks, ConstantArray[White, Length@ticks]}], 
 Ticks -> ticks]
```

[image: Out2]

Comment: thank you for introducing another potentially useful undocumented option :)